# How to put date column into macro variable SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset that has 2 date columns.The date columns in dataset1 are formatted like "01/01/2024"

I put them both into a macro variable like this:-

```
%if &DateType. = date1 %then %do;

proc sql no print;
select date1 into: date separated by ', '
from dataset1;
quit;

%end;
%else %if &DateType. = date2 %then %do;

proc sql no print;
select date2into: date separated by ', '
from dataset1;
quit;
%end;
```

I want to use this macro variable to use in a where statement:-

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *
from dataset1
where &date. > '01Dec2028'd
;
quit;
```

However, I keep getting the "ERROR: Syntax error, expecting one of the following.." in my macro valuable. Do I need to change the format?

Comment: Why are you making a comma delimited list of values if you want to compare it to a single date?  Do the DATE1 and DATE2 variables have a FORMAT attached?  If so then the string generated into the macro variable will not be valid to use as a date (even if there was only one).  You need either a digit string that represents the number of days, like `23350` or a quoted string that can be read by the DATE informat with the letter d appended, like `'06DEC2023'd`.  You could try `select &datetype format=32. into :date trimmed from dataset1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date resolves to more than one date, you'll be passing in a comma-separated list of numeric dates. In other words, `&date` may resolve to:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *
from dataset1
where 23330,23331 > '01Dec2028'd
;
quit;
```

You will need to select a single date from your table from `dataset1`. You can do this by selecting the max date or min date. Additionally, if no valid dates exist in `dataset1`, it could also pass a missing value to it, so you'll need to verify that a nonmissing date exists within the table. For example:

```
proc sql no print;
select max(date1) into: date
from dataset1
where NOT missing(date1)
quit;

%if(&sqlobs = 0) %then %do;
    %put ERROR: No valid dates exist in DATASET1.;
    %abort;
%end;
```